# Folding a piece of paper

Tags: mathematics, geometry, paper-folding

On the table lies a rectangular piece of paper $ABCD$ of area $100$. 
Cosmo folds the rectangle once along a straight line, so that afterwards 
corner $C$ lies exactly on top of corner $A$. 
The folded piece of paper forms a pentagon.

> **Question:** What is the largest possible area of this pentagon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no largest area, but the area can be made as close as wanted to 75.

1. Let's imagine our rectangle. It has diagonal $AC$, centre $O$; let's say $AB$ is the longest side and $H$ is the middle of $AB$.
2. The rectangle will be folded along a line $p$, which is perpendicular to $AC$ at point $O$. $p$ also crosses $AB$ at some point $M$.
3. It is easy to note that when we fold the overlapped area will be of size $2*Size(AOM)$. The pentagon area is $Sp = 100-2*Size(AOM)$. In order to achieve biggest pentagon we need to make overlap as small as possible.
4. But, $AOM$ always includes $AOH$ and $Size(AOH) = \frac{100}{8}$. Thereby $Sp = 100-2*Size(AOM) < 100-\frac{100}{4} = 75$.
5. Finally, let's note that making $\frac{AB}{AD}$ ratio big enough we can make point $M$ as close as needed to point $H$ making $Size(AOM)$ as close as needed to $\frac{100}{8}$ and thereby $Sp$ to 75.

Comment: Can someone make a diagram for this? I'm having trouble following. It seems obvious to me that a trivial max area is 100 and, based on your text, the largest area the pentagon could have would be arbitrarily close to 75 with that acting more as a limit than an actual (achievable) max, right?

Comment: @EngineerToast, yes, the largest area the pentagon could have would be arbitrarily close to 75 with that acting more as a limit than an actual (achievable) max